# How to inflate part of string

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, zlib, inflate

While building a NNTP client in NodeJS, I have encountered the following problem. When calling the XZVER command, the first data I receive from the socket connection contains both a string and an inflated string;

```
224 compressed data follows (zlib version 1.2.3.3)
^*�u�@����`*�Ti���d���x�;i�R��ɵC���eT�����U'�|/S�0���� rd�
                                                   z�t]2���t�bb�3ѥ��>�͊0�ܵ��b&b����<1/    �C�<[<��d���:��VW̡��gBBim�$p#I>5�cZ�*ψ%��u}i�k�j
                                                                                                                                    �u�t���8�K��`>��im
```

When I split this string and try to inflate it like this;

```
lines = chunk.toString().split('\r\n');
response = lines.shift();

zlib.inflate(new Buffer(lines.shift()), function (error, data) {
    console.log(arguments);
    callback();
});
```

I receive the following error;

```
[Error: invalid code lengths set] errno: -3, code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR'
```

Any help is welcome, I am kinda stuck here :(

**UPDATE**

After implementing the answer of mscdex, the whole function looks like this;

```
var util = require('util'),
    zlib = require('zlib'),
    Transform = require('stream').Transform;

function CompressedStream () {
  var self = this;

  this._transform = function (chunk, encoding, callback) {
    var response = chunk.toString(),
        crlfidx = response.indexOf('\r\n');

    response = response.substring(0, crlfidx);
    console.log(response);

    zlib.gunzip(chunk.slice(crlfidx + 2), function (error, data) {
      console.log(arguments);
      callback();
    });
  };

  Transform.call(this/*, { objectMode: true } */);
};

util.inherits(CompressedStream, Transform);

module.exports = CompressedStream;
```

Comment: Are you sure it's supposed to be `gunzip()` and not `inflate()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my chunks were incorrectly encoded. By removing `socket.setEncoding('utf8');`, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably avoid using `split()` in case those two bytes are in the raw data. You might try something like this instead:

```
var response = chunk.toString(),
    crlfidx = response.indexOf('\r\n');
// should probably check crlfidx > -1 here ...
response = response.substring(0, crlfidx);

zlib.inflate(chunk.slice(crlfidx + 2), function (error, data) {
    console.log(arguments);
    callback();
});
```

However if you're doing this inside a 'data' event handler, you should be aware that you may not get the data you expect in a single chunk. Specifically you could get a CRLF split between chunks or you could get multiple responses in a single chunk.

Comment: Instead of a 'data' event hander it's in a _transform function, but I am sure that I receive everything in one call for now.
Your solution isn't quite working, it still gives me the same error as I had before :(

Comment: You will probably have to create an inflate stream and write to that instead of trying to inflate partial chunks.

Comment: You're probably better off having the main NNTP parser read the XZVER response and then just piping however much data following the response (past the CRLF) into an inflate stream (via `zlib.createInflate()`). It doesn't look like XZVER is an official extension or anything, so I'm not sure how you know when to stop inflating, but I would definitely separate the two so that you don't have to have a separate `CompressedStream` that is looking for the response AND data.

Comment: I dived a bit more into the problem and compared my NodeJS code with other clients in other languages. When I look into a similar Python client, I see that they are suppressing the zlib headers (https://github.com/vasc/usenet/blob/6d7c806285e047e3d625ac48a7cb7933a80ca617/nntpextensions.py#L24). Do you know if that's possible in NodeJS? I've added `({ windowBits: -15 })` but that gave me an error like `Invalid windowBits: -15`.

Comment: Yeah this stupidest thing was causing the issue. When comparing the socket output with my PHP variant, I noticed the chunks where differently encoded. So when removing `socket.setEncoding('utf8');` in  the NodeJS code, the string can be correctly inflated :)